# Regular Expression pattern to match a math expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following expression:

```
"3 + 2 * ((1 + 1 - (2 + 4))) + 112 * 31 - ((1+1) - 14 + 1)"
```

I want to split the expression with the top level parentesis

For example:

```
String Expression = "3 + 2 * ((1 + 1 - (2 + 4))) + 112 * 31 - ((1+1) - 14 + 1)";
String[] result = Regex.Split(expression, "??");
```

Expected output:

```
//result[0] = 3 + 2 *
//result[1] = (1 + 1 - (2 + 4))
//result[2] = + 112 * 31 -
//result[3] = 3 + 2 *
//result[4] = (1+1) - 14 + 1
```

Comment: You're better off writing a parser for this (or, best of, just search for one - there are some good ones out there already). Arithmetic is like html - not _regular_.

Comment: What is a "fallow expression"?  Was it just a typo, or is this some sort of notation?

Comment: I agree with Joel, but if you really want to do this in Regex (if you're looking for a challenge and/or you hate yourself) - you may be interested in .NET's Balanced Pattern matching. But as Joel said, a Lexer/Parser is a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex does what you want since you are using .NET. It uses a feature unique to .NET called balancing groups.

```
^[^(]*(?=\()|(?<=\()(?>[^()]+|\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))(?=\))|(?(depth)|[^\(\)]+)
```

The following code:

```
string expression = "3 + 2 * ((1 + 1 - (2 + 4))) + 112 * 31 - ((1+1) - 14 + 1)";
string pattern = @"^[^(]*(?=\()|(?<=\()(?>[^()]+|\((?<depth>)|\)(?<-depth>))*(?(depth)(?!))(?=\))|(?(depth)|[^\(\)]+)";
MatchCollection results = Regex.Matches(expression,pattern);
```

Results in the following values populating the results array:

```
//results[0] = 3 + 2 * 
//results[1] = (1 + 1 - (2 + 4))
//results[2] =  + 112 * 31 - 
//results[3] = (1+1) - 14 + 1
```

Here is a relevant blog post about balancing groups: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups

Answer (score 3):

This isn't normally a job for regular expressions.  However, this [msdn blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx) suggests that it may be possible in the .net version using an extension called "Balanced Matching".

Not being a c# developer, I don't think I can finish answering, but perhaps this will help.

You might be better off finding or writing an actual parser though.

Answer (score 1):

This one should get what you need:

```
\(((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!)))\)
```

Check this article for an overview of "nested constructions": http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Nested_RegEx_explained.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try with regex:

```
([^*]+\*)\s*\x28(.+?)\x29\s+([^-]+\-)(.+?)
```

-

```
   string a = "3 + 2 * ((1 + 1 - (2 + 4))) + 112 * 31 - ((1+1) - 14 + 1)";
                Match match = Regex.Match(a, @"([^*]+\*)\s*\x28(.+?)\x29\s+([^-]+\-)(.+?)");
                for (int c = 0, len = match.Length; c < len; c++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[c].Value);
                }
```

Well,I have no any better idea of as parsing this.